# How to show the following operator is linear?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, operator-algebras

Let us consider the linear vector space $P_n(I)$ of all
polynomials defined over an interval $I$ is subset Real Number Set with degrees less than the positive integer $n$ . A basis for this space is given by $\{1, x, x^2, ... , x^{n-1}\}$. We
denote the differentiation with respect to the variable $x$ by the operator $D$.
How can we show that $D : P_n(I)\rightarrow P_{n-1}(I)$ is a linear operator?

I have no ideas. Could you give some hints?

Linearity:

where $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is an operator, $u,v\in X; α\in K$

$T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$

$T(αv) = αT(v)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**: Think how you would go about differentiating $f(x)=x^2+x^3$ or $g(x)=a\cdot x^9, \ \ a\in \Bbb{R}$.

> **Hint 2.** The derivative is really a limit. In that way, the reasoning relies upon two limit properties.

---

Assume all limits exist. Here $u_i=u_i(x)$.

> **Theorem 1.** $$\lim\left(\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lim u_i$$

---

> **Theorem 2.** $$\lim[a\cdot u (x)]=a\cdot\lim u(x), \ \ a\in\Bbb{R}$$